# How to use regex match end of line in Windows

Tags: regex, linux, grep, newline

I have a .txt file created in Windows and now should be edited in Linux. I want to match the end of a line with grep. Let's say the content of the line I am going to find is "foo bar" in file `bar`. Then I issue the command `grep 'r$' bar`, but no output yielded.

Given in Windows a new line consists of '\r\n', different from Linux/Unix a single '\n', I think there must be something subtle related to this. Then I convert the file with [dos2unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) and voila, it works.

How can I match the content without convert the original file?

Comment: Since you've asked this, GNU grep seems to have fixed this issue, apparently by stripping carriage return characters entirely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your grep supports `-P` (perl-regexp), then to match a CRLF:

```
grep -P '\r$' file
```

or:

grep <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> file

(<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> will produce `^M`)

Answer (score 13):

Use a pattern which matches both line ends: `\r?\n`

Comment: Could you explain what is the purpose of the first 'r' in 'r\r?\n'? Thanks!

Comment: @apollo It's a typo but SO doesn't allow me to fix my own post (1. Your change is too small, 2. The edit queue is full). Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try with [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
awk '/r$/' RS='\r\n' bar
```

or

```
awk '/r\r$/' bar
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue in [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (WSL), running GNU Bash (v4.3.48) on Ubuntu. None of the suggestions above worked for me, but the following did (thanks to @phuclv for the tip to use `\015` instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>).

```
grep -Prno "TOKEN[^\015\012]*" *
```

I wanted to match from `TOKEN` to the end of line and was getting back blanks. So I tried matching all the non carriage returns (`\015`), and non newlines (`\012`) after `TOKEN`.

Comment: `grep -P 'TOKEN\r?\n'` definitely works. So does `grep -P 'TOKEN\r$' file`. Your command is finding *TOKEN followed by zero or more non-CR characters until the first CR*, which obviously doesn't find **TOKEN at the end of the line**

Comment: besides, instead of Ctrl+V-Ctrl+M, just use its character code like `\u000D`, `\x0D` or `\015` depending on which command is used

Comment: @phuclv—I am not trying to match token _at_ end of line. I'm trying to match _from_ token _to_ end of line (looking for TODOs or FIXMEs). I did try (and retry) `grep -P 'TOKEN.*\r?\n'`, and it definitely does _not_ work for me in WSL. But thank you very much for the pointer to the octal representation of `^M`, that's super handy and it works in a bash alias, whereas `^M` gave me trouble in that regard.