# Windows 10 Ubuntu WSL fails to display grep output filenames

Tags: ubuntu, grep, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using

```
grep -rnl "./" -e "search_string"
```

to search a folder's file contents for a "search_string" but it doesn't display filenames. The "-H" option (force filename in output) doesn't change the output. The "-l" option (return only filenames in output) prints several blank lines proportional to the number of files that contain the "search_string" (I have a vague idea how many files contain it) i.e. grep appears to be returning the filenames but the WSL is failing to print them.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6289286/3029276) may be related—the carriage return character may be causing the blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share a screenshot of what you DO see?

I ran your script in a folder containing a file called `hello.txt` that contains the word "world", and I DO see the names of the files containing "world":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Use Windows CMD instead of PowerShell.**

I encountered the same issue when using PowerShell. Switching to a regular CMD window let me see the filenames again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and I don't know why, but as a workaround, using Git Bash instead of WSL works perfectly.